# How to prevent mouse event when a sheet display?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspanel, cocoa-sheet

I found that the `NSView`'s `rightMouseUp` could still be active when a sheet display.I used this code.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:editPanel 
   modalForWindow:window 
    modalDelegate:self 
   didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
      contextInfo:nil];
```

I want to forbid `rightMouseUp`.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is the default behavior for osx.So the only solution is that get the right mouse event and do nothing when the sheet display.